# How to change the default shell in Cygwin?

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to change my default shell from bash to zsh in cygwin.

1. The normal unix command `chsh` isn't available on cygwin
2. The etc/passwd file it seems isn't used anymore in existing versions of cygwin.

So how else can the default shell be changed ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer depends on how you start Cygwin.

If you start Cygwin with *Cygwin.bat*, modify the last line of `/Cygwin.bat` (usually `C:\cygwin\` or `C:\cygwin64\`).

If you start Cygwin with *mintty*, then add the shell as a parameter:  `mintty /usr/bin/zsh -`

Comment: Thank you, I am using Conemu. Had to change the `sh.exe` to `zsh.exe` in Conemu Settings > startup > tasks > bash Cygwin Bash > `set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & %ConEmuDrive%\CygWin\bin\sh.exe --login -i`

Comment: @gyaani_guy I am just using ConEmu to execute `CygWin\bin\zsh.exe`. `sh.exe --login` will launch Bash, how do you change that? Or does it not matter anyway? I imagine `sh.exe --login` is unnecessarily executing `sh` before `zsh`...

Comment: @deed02392 I am not sure I understand.. but the exact command I am using is `set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & %ConEmuDrive%\CygWin\bin\zsh.exe --login -i` hth

Comment: @gyaani_guy thanks, I was confused because in your first comment you seemed to imply that you start zsh with `sh.exe`. Now I realise I just didn't read your message correctly :-)

Comment: The mintty example didn't quite work for me. It had issues until I made it a login shell by adding `-l`:

`mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico /usr/bin/zsh -l -`

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1134672/7444) for a better solution.

Comment: This is the only answer that directly allows you to directly pass the `-l` flag to `zsh`, so this is the only answer that allows you to have a proper *login* `zsh` instance started.

Answer (score 33):

If you run `mintty.exe` directly or run Cygwin Terminal from the start menu or desktop (which is a shortcut to mintty.exe), you can set the SHELL environment variable in Windows to `/usr/bin/zsh`.

On Windows 7:

1. Press Windows key.
2. Start typing "environment".
3. When it appears, select "Edit environment variables for your account".

The rest should be self-explanatory.

Comment: This seriously needs more up-votes. I've never seen this documented anywhere, and it's obviously the intended method.

Comment: For those who don't want to rely on search to find the appropriate panel, right-click the Start menu and select "System" to launch the System control panel.  Then click "Advanced system settings" from the left-side column.  On the "System Properties" window that pops up, click "Environment Variables..." to launch the environment variable editor.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: Choose 'User Variables for xxxx'. Then Add New Variable, Name SHELL, Value /usr/bin/zsh . Launch a new Mintty Window and you start in zsh .. no need to restart windows

Comment: This does appear to be the slickest way to specify the desired Cygwin shell. Is it documented? Couldn't find it searching the cygwin site.

Comment: It's a documented feature of mintty. See https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html. There are other ways to get to the Cygwin terminal, without using mintty, so this is not a universal solution.

Answer (score 18):

Copied from [my answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37815158/36388):

---

Instead of creating a passwd file, which Cygwin [recommends against](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mkpasswd.html)<sup>1</sup>, you could [edit /etc/nsswitch.conf](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch).  Add or edit the following line:

```
db_shell: /usr/bin/fish
```

The down/up side of this method is that, if you have multiple users, this change affects all of them.  The up/up side is that it's dead simple.  The only catch is that you have to restart Cygwin.

If you *do* use mkpasswd after this change, it will use your new default shell for all users that are allowed to log on.

---

<sup>1</sup> The mkpasswd documentation says this:

> Don't use this command to generate a local /etc/passwd file, unless you really need one. See the Cygwin User's Guide for more information.

I can't really find any solid reasoning in the [user's guide](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygwin-ug-net.html), other than a mention that you'll have to regenerate the /etc/passwd and /etc/group files if your users and groups change, which I suppose is a decent enough reason.  I can say that the process is somewhat error prone for newbies.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

This is a hack: put this as the first line of your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
exec zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

My hosting service, dreamhost.com, has an option box in their user edit screen.  It can choose among four different shells and looks somewhat like this

```
User Type: (Click one of these three buttons) 
  * FTP user - allows login via FTP only.   
  * SFTP user - allows login via SFTP only.
  * Shell user - allows login via both SSH and FTP. 
        Shell Type: ____/usr/bin/tcsh_____  
Disallow FTP?:  ___
```